# Explaining an observation in thesis having no reasoning

Tags: thesis, writing, writing-style

During my machine learning master thesis, I came across some observation which increased accuracy of my result. For the observation, I am unable to find the theoretical justification. How to approach this observation in my result and conclusion of thesis report. As this observation is really differentiating my work from others work.

Comment: What does your advisor say?

Comment: You might note it as an empirical finding, one suggesting further research. Et voilà, you have your next side project.

Comment: We can not tell you what it means in the abstract. It might be interesting, it might be an artefact of the experiment, it might be a bug. Talk to your advisor. Also, a good idea is to run some sanity check on simple cases or cases where you know what to expect.

Comment: You’ll also want to demonstrate by hook or by crook that it’s producing results obtainable in other, accepted ways.

Comment: I would try to explain the observations. Conduct more experiments to test the reasons that led to the observations.  This is part of research.  Also, you are in the best position to explain the observations.

Comment: @Prof.SantaClaus "I would try to explain the observations." Good luck with that. Machine learning is notorious for being rife with poorly understood black boxes. It's a notable problem that the field faces.

Comment: @nick012000 the operative word being 'try'.

Comment: My advisor told me first try to find the reasoning and last resort is mention it as a empirical result. But he indicates that just saying emperical results is not such a nice ideas.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That seems to be the sort of thing that would go in a "future work" section. You have anecdotal evidence that might lead you to make an hypothesis that could be tested (in future).

If you can replicate the results it is a bit stronger, but if the accuracy of your basic approach isn't sufficient, perhaps you aren't done yet.

It may not be quite as important for a MS thesis, but in general, a future work plan is a big plus.